# Execute command if had no reply from user

Tags: shell, command-line

I am writing one script, that must wait for some time. If user didn't get reply within that time, the script must exit .

eg

```
printf " **YES or NO** "
read choice

if [[ $choice == "yes" ]] ; then
    some commends
else
    exit 0
fi
```

if user didn't reply [yes or no] within 30 seconds it has to go for the "else"-branch.

How can we do it?

I tried like this:

```
read choice || sleep 30
```

Comment: read input </dev/tty depending on where you are reading from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `read` with `-t` (timeout) key.

```
-t timeout
                 Cause  read  to time out and return failure if a complete
                 line of input is not read within timeout seconds.   time‐
                 out  may  be  a  decimal number with a fractional portion
                 following the decimal point.  This option is only  effec‐
                 tive  if  read is reading input from a terminal, pipe, or
                 other special file; it has no effect  when  reading  from
                 regular  files.  If timeout is 0, read returns success if
                 input is available  on  the  specified  file  descriptor,
                 failure  otherwise.   The exit status is greater than 128
                 if the timeout is exceeded.
```

So, in your case:

```
read -t 30 answer
[ "$?" > 128 ] && TIMEOUT=YES
if [ "$answer" = yes ]
then
   echo User replied yes
else
   if [ "$TIMEOUT" = YES ]
   then
     echo User did not reply
   else
     echo User replied something other
   fi
fi
```

Comment: @Igor Chubin ,Your script is not working properly in last else part . After read if the answer is  not  "yes" then the last else part will execute but executing the second else part so I made some changes in the post .